# how to concat dates and retrieve under month of dates

Tags: mysql

I am using holiday table as:

[image: holiday table]

I want to retrive 1 row having columns Jan To Dec and data as all holidays in respective month.
I tried with

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=1 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as JAN, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=2 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as FEB, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=3 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as MAR, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=4 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as APR, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=5 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as MAY, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=6 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as JUN, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=7 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as JUL, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=8 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as AUG, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=9 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as SEP, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=10 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as OCT, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=11 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as NOV, 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(hd.holiday_date)=12 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) ELSE NULL END) as DECE
FROM `holiday` `hd`
WHERE `year` = '2020'
GROUP BY MONTH(hd.holiday_date)
```

with group by getting result but multiple rows are returing as

[image]

without group by returning single row but not getting under proper month as

[image]

Please suggest me correct way. Thanks.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the other way around:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN MONTH(holiday_date)=3 
                         THEN CONCAT_WS('#',holiday_date,holiday_name) 
                         ELSE NULL END) AS 'March',
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN MONTH(holiday_date)=4 
                         THEN CONCAT_WS('#',holiday_date,holiday_name) 
                         ELSE NULL END) AS 'April'
FROM   holiday
WHERE  YEAR=2020
GROUP  BY YEAR;
```

Fiddle example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2DUDuiGM4T12Ah7hxuPTdB/1

Answer (score 1):

1) Create inner query where group them by months

```
SELECT
  MONTH(hd.holiday_date) as m, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) as name
FROM holiday as hd
GROUP BY MONTH(hd.holiday_date)
```

2) In outer query do something like

```
SELECT 
  MAX(case when m = 1 then name else "" end) as Jan
  MAX(case when m = 2 then name else "" end) as Feb
FROM (inner)
```

So the result will be

```
SELECT 
  MAX(case when m = 1 then name else "" end) as Jan,
  MAX(case when m = 2 then name else "" end) as Feb
  // etc
FROM (
  SELECT
    MONTH(hd.holiday_date) as m, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hd.holiday_date, '#', hd.holiday_name)) as name
  FROM holiday as hd
  GROUP BY MONTH(hd.holiday_date) 
) as grouped
```